# Linking app.route to app.layout in Flask/Dash under waitress

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I have tried to find an answer to this, but have been unsuccessful. I think I lack the understanding as to what is going on.

I have a dash app, and am trying to deploy to a server. I've wrapped it in Flask and am using waitress to serve it up.

The app is simple, single page of HTML, couple of drop-downs, these drive a report. I've excluded the details.

My problem is I can't see how to trigger the app.layout (where the HTML sits) from the @app.route statement.

File layout is:

- server.py
- myappname (dir)
- - **init**.py
- - myappname.py
- - views.py

Code (skeletal)

```
# server.py

from waitress import serve
from myappname import app
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8050)



# myappname/__init__.py
    
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
    
app = Flask(__name__)

import myappname.views


# myappname/views.py

from myappname import app
import flask 
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.redirect('/myappname') 

# myappname/myappname.py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

# ... various procedures

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/myappname')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(rhubarb
    ),
    html.Div([rhubarb,rhubarb
    ])

@server.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.redirect('/myappname')

@app.callback(
    Output('Elementy', 'options'),
    [Input('Elementx', 'value')])
def fiddle1(selected_element):
    return blah

@app.callback(
    Output('Elementz', 'value'),
    [Input('Elementy', 'options')])
def fiddle1(available_options):
    return blah
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up tossing most of the small files, put the app directly in **init**.py.
server.py now reads:

```
from waitress import serve
from myappname import app
application = app.server
serve(application, host='0.0.0.0', port=8050)
```